# Use an h:commandButton to toggle rich:dataScroller

Tags: xhtml, richfaces

Has anyone used a `commandButton` to toggle a `rich:dataScroller` on and off?  Would I need to make a bean to keep track of if the `rich:dataScroller` is active or not and make the action of the `commandButton` to toggle the bean?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by on/off? Does it means show/hide? If so, you can do something like this.
Assume that you have following table which has a `datascroller` and a `commandButton` below the table.

```
<h:form>
     <rich:dataTable var="_usr" value="#{myBean.users}" rows="5">
        <rich:column>
          #{_usr.userName}
        </rich:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
          <rich:datascroller id="myScroller" />
        </f:facet>
     </rich:dataTable>
     <a4j:commandButton value="Show/Hide" onclick="toggleScroller(#{rich:element('myScroller')});"/>
</h:form>
```

The javascript function which shows/hides the `datascroller` is as below.

```
<script>
  function toggleScroller(scroller) {
      if(scroller.style.display == 'none') {
          scroller.style.display = ''
        } else {
            scroller.style.display = 'none'
        }
    }
</script>
```

Or you can use the `rendered` property of the `<rich:datascroller>` to render it according to a bean property.